# variables float no equals in php why?

Tags: php

hello I have a problem wtich two variables in php. i have this code:

```
     var_dump($total);echo '<br/>';
     var_dump($reserva->getAdelanto());
     if ($total == $reserva->getAdelanto()){
        $total = 0;
        echo "hello";
        }
    else
        $total = $total - $reserva->getAdelanto();
```

print :

```
float(3940.2) 
float(3940.2)
```

but does not enter the if when the two variables are equal. anyone knows why is that? greetings and thanks.

Comment: I've faced this problem in C++ too. To solve this what I do is to check their difference. for an example if(abs($x-$y)<$eps)echo "They are equal"; where $eps = 0.000000001 or the tolerance value

Answer (score 1):

May be try with abs like

```
if ((abs($a)-abs($b)) <= 0.00001) {
   echo "same";
}
```

Or

```
if (abs($a - $b) <= 0.00001) {
   echo "same";
}
```

Or you also try like

```
var_dump( bccomp($a, $b) == 0 )
```

returns true if they are same

Comment: it should be abs($a-$b)

Comment: for $a = 10, $b = 5, your code will say that these 2 are same :P

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet I have added that also...could you see once,and also my third ans

Comment: well my second comment is for the first code. for $a = 10, $b = 5, abs($a)-abs($b)=-5 which is less than 0.00001 but these two are not same. We need the absolute value of the difference, not the difference of absolute values  :)